# fancybox - custom button

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am attempting to add a custom button to FancyBox 2's button helper.  The new button shows fine, but I can not get any on click behavior with it... the binding does nothing on click.  What is the secret to adding your own button with this?

Here is what I was trying to do just to test the button on click to see if it works.  Nothing happens.

```
// init the screenshots
$(".fancybox-screenshots").fancybox({
    prevEffect      : 'none',
    nextEffect      : 'none',
    helpers     : {
        title   : { type : 'inside' },
        buttons : {}
    },
    afterShow: function(){
        $('#fancybox-buttons').on("click", "#btnTest", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('testing');
        });
    } //  afterShow
});
```

Here is the output of the buttons helper :

```
<div id="fancybox-buttons" class="top">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="btnPrev" href="javascript:;" title="Previous"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a class="btnPlay" href="javascript:;" title="Start slideshow"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a class="btnNext" href="javascript:;" title="Next"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a class="btnToggle" href="javascript:;" title="Toggle size"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a id="btnTest" href="javascript:;" title="Test Button"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a class="btnClose" href="javascript:;" title="Close"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**

I have included a jsfiddle - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SX4CX/3/) - the button I added in the fiddle is the second to the last... in this case it is another toggle between toggle and close.  I didn't feel like adding the images for my button. Corrected css.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Comment: what button your are trying to add, it is for what purpose ?

Comment: fiddle added... in this case I just want to show an alert on click so I know the onclick event works... I can easily go from there with my own function after getting this click to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fiddle updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/SX4CX/4/)

```
afterShow: function (opts, obj) {
  $('#fancybox-buttons').on("click", "#btnTest", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('testing');
}
```

Comment: Nice! So all I was missing this whole time was passing opts and obj.  Out of curiosity what do those represent?

Comment: In the custom click event these parameters are not getting used.. However it is used for other buttons like play etc.. See code in fiddle.. I just added click event at the end so that dom has element and it binds click correctly